# How do I extract only the first element from the list?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I'm creating a new column by splitting a variable in an existing column

Category_list is an existing column which has one or more categories a company falls under where multiple categories are separated by pipes (|).

I'm trying to identify the primary category a company falls under by making the assumption that the first one(if there are multiple categories) should be the primary category.

```
 master_frame_ven['primary_sector'] = master_frame_ven['category_list'].str.split(pat = '|')
```

When I did this and executed the code above, the objects which were split got stored in lists in the primary_category column.

To remove them from lists, store them as a separate entity and extract only the first value, I tried to do this,

```
master_frame_ven['primary_sector'] = master_frame_ven['primary_sector'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

When I do this, it throws an error:

```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-66-5dffe0256421> in <module>
>       1 master_frame_ven['primary_sector'] = master_frame_ven['category_list'].str.split(pat = '|')
>       2 
> ----> 3 master_frame_ven['primary_sector'] = master_frame_ven['primary_sector'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
> 
> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

And this is the data frame I'm currently working with.

```
> {'company_permalink': {0: '/organization/-fame',   1:
> '/organization/-qounter',   3: '/organization/-the-one-of-them-inc-', 
> 4: '/organization/0-6-com',   5: '/organization/004-technologies'}, 
> 'funding_round_permalink': {0:
> '/funding-round/9a01d05418af9f794eebff7ace91f638',   1:
> '/funding-round/22dacff496eb7acb2b901dec1dfe5633',   3:
> '/funding-round/650b8f704416801069bb178a1418776b',   4:
> '/funding-round/5727accaeaa57461bd22a9bdd945382d',   5:
> '/funding-round/1278dd4e6a37fa4b7d7e06c21b3c1830'}, 
> 'funding_round_type': {0: 'venture',   1: 'venture',   3: 'venture',  
> 4: 'venture',   5: 'venture'},  'funding_round_code': {0: 'B', 1: 'A',
> 3: 'B', 4: 'A', 5: nan},  'funded_at': {0: '05-01-2015',   1:
> '14-10-2014',   3: '30-01-2014',   4: '19-03-2008',   5:
> '24-07-2014'},  'raised_amount_usd': {0: 10000000.0,   1: nan,   3:
> 3406878.0,   4: 2000000.0,   5: nan},  'permalink': {0: '/organization/-fame',   1: '/organization/-qounter',   3:
> '/organization/-the-one-of-them-inc-',   4: '/organization/0-6-com',  
> 5: '/organization/004-technologies'},  'name': {0: '#fame',   1:
> ':Qounter',   3: '(THE) ONE of THEM,Inc.',   4: '0-6.com',   5: '004
> Technologies'},  'homepage_url': {0: 'http://livfame.com',   1:
> 'http://www.qounter.com',   3: 'http://oneofthem.jp',   4:
> 'http://www.0-6.com',   5: 'http://004gmbh.de/en/004-interact'}, 
> 'category_list': {0: 'Media',   1: 'Application Platforms|Real
> Time|Social Network Media',   3: 'Apps|Games|Mobile',   4: 'Curated
> Web',   5: 'Software'},  'status': {0: 'operating',   1: 'operating', 
> 3: 'operating',   4: 'operating',   5: 'operating'},  'country_code':
> {0: 'IND', 1: 'USA', 3: nan, 4: 'CHN', 5: 'USA'},  'state_code': {0:
> '16', 1: 'DE', 3: nan, 4: '22', 5: 'IL'},  'region': {0: 'Mumbai',  
> 1: 'DE - Other',   3: nan,   4: 'Beijing',   5: 'Springfield,
> Illinois'},  'city': {0: 'Mumbai',   1: 'Delaware City',   3: nan,  
> 4: 'Beijing',   5: 'Champaign'},  'founded_at': {0: nan,   1:
> '04-09-2014',   3: nan,   4: '01-01-2007',   5: '01-01-2010'}, 
> 'primary_sector': {0: 'Media',   1: 'Application Platforms',   3:
> 'Apps',   4: 'Curated Web',   5: 'Software'}}
```

​
I don't understand which part of it is a float and why I'm getting this error precisely. What should I be doing differently to extract only the primary category from the list and store it as a string rather than keeping it as a list?

Comment: `master_frame_ven['category_list'].str.split(pat = '|').str[0]` or `master_frame_ven['category_list'].str.split(pat = '|').str.get(0)`

Comment: `I don't understand which part of it is a float and why I'm getting this error precisely.` Please provide the dataframe, create [mcve], post `df.to_dict()` if df is large post `df.head(10).to_dict()`

Comment: @Ch3steR 
Thank you so much! You are my savior! .str.get() method worked. Also Pardon me for not knowing how to post the dataframe. I'm new to stack overflow.

Comment: @Ch3steR Do check and let me know if this in the format that you asked for. I've posted the first 5 lines on the dataset after converting it into a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You chose not to supply a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),
which would help folks check proposed solutions.

You used:

> ```
> lambda x: x[0]
> ```

You'll be happier with:

> ```
> lambda x: str(x[0])
> ```

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. Pardon me for not supplying a reproducible example. How else do you think I should've framed my problem to make it a reproducible example?

Comment: The help document is pretty clear on that topic. You should show how to assign sample data to the df. As it stands, when a would-be collaborator tries to run your code, he is greeted with this diagnostic: `NameError: name 'master_frame_ven' is not defined`